# Strange symbol for two functions

Tags: symbols

I am translating one dyploma from english, so i find strange symbol[image: sy]

Help me find code for this, please

Comment: Look here first: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character

Comment: @Davislor, thanks a lot, service was useless, but i find vertical part of this symbol in symbol list - it is a \multimapdotbothvert from package "pxfonts". But know i cannot understand sybmols that looks like composition symbol in math(horizontal symbols)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to do it. Use a better name than `\strangesymbol` (somebody might suggest `\zzz`, but I don't recommend it).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\strangesymbol}{%
  \mathrel{\circ}%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\strange@symbol\relax}%
  \mathrel{\circ}%
}

\newcommand{\strange@symbol}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \m@th\offinterlineskip
    \sbox\z@{\scalebox{0.7}{$#1\bullet$}}%
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
      \usebox\z@\cr
      \noalign{\kern-0.3\ht\z@}%
      $#1|$\cr
      \noalign{\kern-0.3\ht\z@}%
      \usebox\z@\cr
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
f_j\strangesymbol f_k \qquad \sum_{f_j\strangesymbol f_k} x
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It took me more than an hour to invent this code because I had to find the right position for the symbols. I hope he's answered your question. In truth there is specific symbol `\multimapdotbothvert` from `boisik` package but if I put this in, I'm gonna lose the mathematical fonts of computer modern. I hope that I have answered your question.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
\newcommand\tdots{\mathrel{\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mkern-4mu{-}\mkern-4mu\boldsymbol{\cdot}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{\overset{\mkern-20mu f_j\circ \,\,\circ f_k}{}\mkern-35mu{\rotatebox{90} 
{$\tdots$}}}{[p_e(\rho \ldots)]}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, i find this command also, but didnot have time to post it here) Thanks anyway. And one more: instead of package \boisik it allows to use \pxfonts. And little circles around this vertical symbol are \circ